# YouTrack Stopwatch-style Work Timer - Work Item not added

Tags: timer, youtrack

We are using the **Stopwatch-style Work Timer** [Link to YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/Workflow-w). After clicking on ,,Stop" the work item is not added anymore. Where can we search for help?

[image]

I removed the workflow and field and added them again. I checked to code and compared it to original code.

Comment: Firstly, check that [time tracking](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/server/Time-Management-Tutorial.html) is in fact set up in the project. If so, then perform basic troublshooting of the rule — make sure that there are no errors on the workflows' page, add console logs to the rule to see if it's executed, then check the [editor's console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/server/Web-based-Workflow-Editor.html#workflow-editor-console-toolbar) (!not the browser!) for more details and error.

Comment: Hi @SergeyMerzlov. First thanks for your help!
1. Projects -> Project -> Edit Project -> Time Tracking | It is enabled 
2. Basic Troubleshooting - No errors on workflows page
3. Basic Troubleshooting - Console Logs
4. Editor's Console

Comment: Hi @SergeyMerzlov. First thanks for your help! I don't know what happened, but not it works again.
1. Projects -> Project -> Edit Project -> Time Tracking | It is enabled ###
(was not required) 2. Basic Troubleshooting - No errors on workflows page ###
(was not required) 3. Basic Troubleshooting - Console Logs ###
(was not required) 4. Editor's Console